# Why addClickListener is not reconized?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, methods, vaadin8

I know it's a basic question... But I'm still learning and I don't know what's happening !

I created a vaadin 8 project with Eclipse. I used this link to create some components : https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20simple%20login%20view

But I would like to add :

```
Button sample = new Button("Click");
sample.addClickListener(event -> Notification.show("The button was clicked", Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION));
```

But the method addClikcListener is not reconized !

EDIT :

Yes, I can do :

```
Button sample = new Button("Click", new Button.ClickListener() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    }
)};
```

EDIT 2 : 
The error is :

```
Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token  SimpleLoginMainView.java
```

Comment: Don't know Vaadin, but it appears you can add listeners via the second argument to the `Button` constructor. Try that.

Comment: I edited the post to add the example. Yes, but I tried to understand why it's not working direcly... because I cannot use any method on my button...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to understand why I cannot use this method. It's strange, isn't it?

Comment: My thought was it may have been removed. I couldn't verify that though as the vaadin site is down currently.

Comment: I'm blocked too because it's down !

Comment: Ya. Unfortunate timing. I was able to find examples on other sites that verify your code does appear to be valid, but without an official source, it's hard to say. Also, again, I hadn't even heard of Vaadin before reading this question, so I'm just shooting in the dark. Good luck.

Comment: Also, please post the **exact** error. Sometimes key details get missed when you manually write them.

Comment: Which `.` is the error happening on? And that's a very different error than what you originally said it was. That error doesn't suggest that `addClickListener` doesn't exist, it suggests a syntax error.

Comment: You seem to have top-level expressions in a class. Is `Button sample = new Button("Click");` inside a method?

Comment: Could you add that as answer? Yeah... I don't know how I can do that... but yes.... I did bad bad bad mistake ! And yes it's a duplication because it's the same error and same resolution ! Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it is a dupe, doesn't the other answer answer the question?

Comment: @FannyV Remove the second argument from your addClickListener.